# Reading csv file one line at a time in c language

Tags: c, csv, file

I have this csv file contain people contact:

```
NAME, NUMBER, ADDRESS, EMAIL
Kevin Mahendra, +62 812-XXX-XXX, Jln. Anggrek Merah 3 No. 54, kevin@gmail.com
Adwi Lanang, +62 821-XXX-XXX, Jln. Ruhui Rahayu, adwi@gmail.com
```

and this is the code:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Number of buckets for TABLE
#define N 26

#define MAX 50

typedef struct Contact
{
    char name[MAX];
    char number[MAX];
    char address[MAX];
    char email[MAX];
    struct Contact* next;
} 
Contact;

// Hash table
Contact *table[N];

int main(void)
{  
    // OPEN CSV FILE
    FILE *file = fopen("contacts.csv", "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error open file!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    while(!feof(file))
    {
        Contact *new = malloc(sizeof(Contact));
        fscanf(file, "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,]", new->name, new->number, new->address, new->email);
        
        printf("%s,%s,%s,%s\n", new->name, new->number, new->address, new->email);

        int index = hash(new->name);
   
        new->next = table[index];
        table[index] = new; 
    }

}
```

As you can see, i try to put each person **contact** into hash table. But it fails to read csv file properly. Because when i try to ***printf*** it, the result is become infinite loop.

BUT it's working when my csv file only contain one line/row. It will ***printf*** the contact inside csv properly. But when i add a new contact/row into csv file, it fails to read.

How can i read csv file one line/row at a time? and maybe also skip the header `NAME, NUMBER, ADDRESS, EMAIL`? Thank you!

Comment: What does the following mean: "Because when i try to printf it, the result is become infinite loop"?

Comment: Please take some time to read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Also please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: @jarmod it just didn't stop print blank in prompt.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude still don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last field on each line is not succeeded by a comma, so you should look for a newline instead. Also to prevent overflow you must never read more than one character less than the buffer length. This can be achieved with a preprocessor trick:

```
#define STR_VALUE(x) STR(x)
#define STR(x) #x

#define MAX 49
#define MAX_STR STR_VALUE(MAX)

typedef struct Contact
{
    char name[MAX + 1];
    char number[MAX + 1];
    char address[MAX + 1];
    char email[MAX + 1];
    struct Contact* next;
}
Contact;
...
fscanf(file,
    "%" MAX_STR "[^,],%" MAX_STR "[^,],%" MAX_STR "[^,],%" MAX_STR "[^\n]",
    new->name, new->number, new->address, new->email);
...
```

In the loop you should stop when the result of fscanf (i.e. the number of scanned tokens) is any other value than four.

Edit 2021-04-06: Macro parameters are expanded before substitution *except* where they appear as operands of # (string representation) or ## (concatenation). Therefor

```
STR(MAX) => #MAX => "MAX"
```

whereas

```
STR_VALUE(MAX) => STR(49) => #49 => "49"
```

Comment: Thank you! This is working. But can you explain it what does this means `#define STR_VALUE(x) STR(x)` `#define STR(x) #x` `#define MAX_STR STR_VALUE(MAX)` ?

Comment: Is there a way i can do to not include header in my csv `NAME, NUMBER, ADDRESS, EMAIL`?

Comment: @KevinkunOfficial For the first question, see updated answer. For the second question, just remove the header from the CSV file, or skip character up to the first newline.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `feof` is wrong - see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/4386427)

Further, you should always check the value returned by `fscanf` to see that you have scanned the expected number of elements.

Try something like:

```
Contact *new = malloc(sizeof(Contact));   // Get a Contact for the first fscanf
if (new == NULL) exit(1);

while(fscanf(file, "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,]", new->name, new->number, new->address, new->email) == 4)
{
    
    printf("%s,%s,%s,%s\n", new->name, new->number, new->address, new->email);

    int index = hash(new->name);

    new->next = table[index];
    table[index] = new; 

    Contact *new = malloc(sizeof(Contact));  // Get a Contact for the next fscanf
    if (new == NULL) exit(1);
}

free(new);  // Free the unused Contact
```

Comment: This looks great. Thanks!

Comment: But why it only **printf** the new->name ? And it also only print one contact/line in csv file?